# I'm getting this Error: Axios Error Network Error ERR_NETWORK

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm following Ania's great tutorial on how to build a full reactApp, but I'm stocked at one point:

https://youtu.be/Q70IMS-Qnjk?t=10865

I reinstalled Axios on the client, when I reinstall I also get many errors.

Even with your code, I don't manage to pass to the onboarding section. And that includes :

```
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
```

I get the following CONSOLE error, which Ania gets too but solves by adding the 3 previous lines( express, cors and json ):

```
posting: ania3@gmail.com 123
AuthModal.js:40 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49489:14)"[[Prototype]]: Error
xhr.js:247          POST http://localhost:8000/signup net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:142
httpMethod @ Axios.js:181
wrap @ bind.js:5
handleSubmit @ AuthModal.js:28
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
```

The issue was with a miss name of the user_id cookie

in the client AuthModal.js I changed userId vs user_id:

setCookie('UserId', response.data.userId)

for

setCookie('UserId', response.data.user_id)

Now I'm getting new errors

UPDATE: I noticed it inserted the user Ania3 in mongoDb, and in FireFox it says I'm logged in, but in Chrome is not.

So, I logged out and when I create a new user, I get the following Error: status of 404

```
posting: ania4@gmail.com 1234
:8000/signup:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
AuthModal.js:40 AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…>\n<pre>Cannot POST /signup</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50745:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49440:66)"[[Prototype]]: Error
```

But this time didn't create user Ania4

When I submit the onboarding form I also get this ERROR: Error: status of 404

```
submitted
xhr.js:247          PUT http://localhost:8000/user 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:247
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:142
httpMethod @ Axios.js:181
wrap @ bind.js:5
handleSubmit @ OnBoarding.js:29
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
OnBoarding.js:34
```